# Using terminal in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, command-line

I felt difficulty in using the terminal. Can some one say the easier to learn this stuff,if you has experience with this.
ex: If i want to modify a file and if i want to update some software etc.,

I want to know the commands for different things and what things we can do in terminal in ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: You should try this [Code Academy course](https://www.codecademy.com/fr/courses/learn-the-command-line). It's free and explain really well the foundations of command line **;)**

Answer (score 0):

and welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Here is a nice guide for starters:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal

It is in english, though, and it does not seem to be your native language. If you tell us what that is, we might be able to find something with a smoother learning curve for you.

Enjoy it!

Answer (score 0):

The first commands to learn and understand are imho:

```
man, ls, cd, less, cat, echo
```

then some more active commands:

```
mkdir, mv, rmdir, rm
```

and some often used "powertools":

```
sudo, grep, find, locate, vi, sed, ...
```

Ubuntu (and Debian) specific commands you might want to get used to are:

```
"apt-cache search", "apt-get update", "apt-get upgrade", "apt-get install"
```

Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

Nodebody provided an excellent list of first commands. To these I would add:

file, type, vim (instead of vi)

I found the book, **The Linux Command Line**, a very good way to learn how to use my system.